# Netsh Commands Cannot Display Correct the result in TextBox

Tags: c#, admin, netsh

```
    class TcpIpCommands
    {
        public string Check()
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\syswow64\netsh.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "int tcp show global";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(737);
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            return p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }

        public string Command(string FileName, string Arguments)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
            p.FileName = FileName;
            p.Arguments = Arguments;
            p.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(737);

            using (Process process = Process.Start(p))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return result;
                }
            }            
        }

        public string Reseting()
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\syswow64\netsh.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"interface tcp reset";
            p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(737);
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            return p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

I have an problem with Command Method and Reseting Method. If i try to execute them I receive in RichTextBox the message
set global command failed on ipv4 the parameter is incorrect

But If i run netsh interface tcp show global or hit the Check Method they info me that the status are change.

here are the buttons

```
        private void BtnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpIpCommands tic = new TcpIpCommands();
            richTextBox1.Text = tic.Check();
        }    
        private void btnChimney_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpIpCommands tic = new TcpIpCommands();
            richTextBox1.Text = tic.Command(@"C:\Windows\system32\netsh.exe", "interface tcp set global chimney=enabled");            
        }    
        private void BtnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpIpCommands tic = new TcpIpCommands();
            richTextBox1.Text = tic.Reseting();
        }
```

I cant understand why RichTextBox shows that message but the process execute succefully.
A note. I have try to run the commands with

```
    StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

and both from
    `C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe`
 and 
`C:\Windows\syswow64\netsh.exe` 
and i get the same error "set global command failed on ipv4 the parameter is incorrect" but the code execute and the parameter change.

Comment: I add a manifest and now programm asked for elevated privileges, but nothing. Hit the button of Chimney, on textbox have "set global command failed on ipv4 the parameter is incorrect" and the value with incorrect parameter change from Disabled to Enabled. Note I have check this in Win 7 64 and Win 10 64.

Comment: Just something that i saw now is that the ipv6 parameters doesnt get effect, only ipv4 parameters change.